# Converting byte array in java to matlab

Tags: java, arrays, matlab

I have a program that works well in Java and I am trying to incorporate it into Matlab. There is an external jar file that I add using `javaclasspath` into Matlab and I am able to use import statements to import the classes into Matlab workspace.

The problem arises, where in the java program I have the following statement:

```
byte[] data = imageUtils.bitmap2jpeg(bm); // imageUtils being the name of the class in external jar and data is an image
```

When I use the corresponding statement in Matlab the resulting data is in int8 format in Matlab.

```
data = imageUtils.bitmap2jpeg(bm);
```

If i create a `fileoutputstream` object in Matlab and write this data, the image that is written is the correct output. However, I am unable to do an imshow on this image directly

Is there any method by which I can directly convert `data` into a matrix in Matlab, such that it is the original image to avoid the intermediate read write operation (mentioned above) ? I have looked at `javaArray` to try to create a byte array directly instead of int8 data, but that is not working.

Comment: What is `bm`?  Is it also an array? Is this a string that contains the path to your image file?  This is not clear in your problem definition.

Comment: It sounds like the issue is not reading bytes into Matlab, but convincing Matlab to interpret a jpeg image in a memory, rather than from a file.

Comment: @Pursuit - Ah ok. That is certainly different.  I didn't understand this from the OP's post.

Comment: bm is another datatype that is created by the external file. However they convert it to a byte array using the function bitmap2jpeg. The problem is making matlab realize that the int8 array is actually an image. Even the size of the `data` is not same as the image size once its written to the hard disk.